# Swagger generation for Java based azure function

Tags: java, azure, swagger, azure-functions

I have to set up swagger in Azure func V2.
seen two options:-

1.**Swashbuckle**- But it seems to be C# specific.

2.**Manually create swagger yaml** and create a http trigger to call it thereby generating the swagger api doc.

does any dependency or package exist to implement swagger for azure funcs V2 in Java to avoid the manual implementation?

Comment: please refer to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFuVxS1JM6g

Comment: But this is a springcloud function deployed to azure i guess.I am creating an HTTP-Triggered function in azure function app for which i am trying to implement swagger documentation.I guess these are entirely different.Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: If so, you can integrate your fucton with API management.   it will generate swagger file automatically. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition

Comment: I am aware about this but we arent allowed to use API management and hence have to find out if swagger can be generated manually.Looking for something similar to swashbuckle but for java based azure functions.

Comment: Regarding the normal swagger sdk, please refer to https://swagger.io/tools/open-source/open-source-integrations/

Comment: craeted a spring boot application and configured it as mentoned here https://blog.nebrass.fr/playing-with-spring-cloud-in-azure-functions/.To enable Swagger 2 i follwed https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api.However even after successful build and run the target folder dont have the swaggerfiles generated.Anything more that needs to be done?